# Determine a "tangential quadrilateral" from 4 points in OpenCv

Tags: opencv, geometry

what I'm trying to do is getting a [tangential quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_quadrilateral) from 4 points using `OpenCv`.

I'm tried an approach where I just take the center of the four points and adding a circle. But this is not always true. Further its very hard to determine the radius of the circle.

Shortly: A tangential quadrilateral is a circle which lies completely within a square. e.g.:

[image]

*Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tangentenviereck.svg CC BY-SA 4.0*

Is there a way in OpenCv for this?

Comment: "quadrilateral is a circle" -- HUH? Seems like you got the definition somewhat mixed up. The black thing is a quadrilateral, the blue thing a circle (in this case an incircle). | That said, you should probably elaborate on what in the image you know, and what you're trying to calculate. (I would assume you know `A B C D` and want to find `M` and `r`)

Answer (score 2):

If you have 4 points A,B, C, D you definitely already have quadrilateral (four-side polygon).

It is not guaranteed that this tangential  is tangential - it is true only if sums of opposite side lengths are equal.

If you really have vertices of tangential tangential - find length of sides a,b,c,d and diagonals p,q and get incircle radius [as](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentialQuadrilateral.html)

```
r = Sqrt(4*p^2*q^2-(a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2)^2)) / (2*(a+b+c+d))
```

There is a lot of formulas for incircle center at wiki page, but I'd use trigonometric approach - get bisector vector of A angle as sum of normalized AB and AD vectors, normalize it, multiply by length |AM|=r/tg(A/2) and add resulting vector to A.

Note that OpenCV is library for image processing, not for geometric calculations.